# How to Add Interop dll to Wix project (dot net)

Tags: c#, .net, dll, vb6, wix

I am referencing a VB6 dll in my dot net project.
to do this I need to register the dll using regsvr32 tool.

when i build my project the Interop dll is getting created in obj folder and not bin folder.

Do I need to add the VB6 dll to wix project and register it. If yes how do I achieve it.
I tried adding it to wix project but as its not created in bin folder i am getting error.

Could anyone please help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You install the vb6 Dll the same as any other file, with the addition that the Heat tool is used to harvest the registration entries from it. You don't need regsvr32.

If you want your interop dll in a specific location at build time, I suggest you explicitly use the tlbimp.exe tool to create the interop dll in the required build location so the WiX build can find it.